# XSSF Counting Missing Rows

Tags: java, excel, xssf

I am trying to write a function that reads in an Excel template and starts writing at a certain row index. However, I'm finding that the numbering skips blank rows in the template. Is there a way to count blank lines during iteration?

I tried to find a row equivalent to the [missing cell policy](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/class-use/Row.MissingCellPolicy.html). I also tried these two styles of iteration:

```
  //simple for loop
  for (Row row : sheet1) {
    for (Cell cell : row) {
       ...
    }
  }

  //iterator
  while (rows.hasNext()) {
      XSSFRow row = ((XSSFRow) rows.next());
      ...
  }
```

Both seem to ignore blank rows. This causes problems because my template has blank lines to separate sections which throws off the indexing of rows, and I have to manually correct the target index for doing tasks like "start writing at row #5 in the sheet".

Comment: Please share, how you have used missing cell policy...

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding, your problem is that you have some rows, which are blank, but you are not able to figure out the blank rows (i.e. having no cells). If I am right, you can use the following check (thought I have not checked it, but I think it should work).

```
if(row!=null){
    for (int cellNo = 0; cellNo < lastColumn; cellNo ++){
        Cell cell = row.getCell(cellNo , Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
        if(cell == null){
            //Code for the Blank Rows
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will show the null values as blank.

```
                for(Row blankRow : sheet)
                {
                    for(int cn=1; cn<blankRow.getLastCellNum()-1; cn++) 
                    {
                        Cell cells = blankRow.getCell(cn, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                    }
                }
```